# Logging to Logstash: separate logs of different applications in one container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, logging, logstash, elastic-stack

I have rails application on passenger web server running in docker container. I'm trying to redirect application logs to Logstash. I redirect rails logs to STDOUT and configure container to use gelf log driver, which redirects STDOUT to given Logstash server. But problem arises: Passenger web server writes his own logs to STDOUT too. And I get mixture of two logs, what make it difficult to separate and analyze.

What is best practices in such situation? How could I label each log stream to separate it in logstash?

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted, you could configure Passenger to write to its own stdout log, but I would avoid using STDOUT as an intermediary for logstash.

Try a library like [logstash-logger](https://github.com/dwbutler/logstash-logger). You could then write to a separate file, socket, or database. I think that's a cleaner approach, and potentially faster depending on the log destination.

Comment: But it would be better. if I could save passenger logs to logstash too

Comment: Also, I could not manage logstash-logger to work by now - I get error of buffer overflow...